# intellij IDEA 13 + CDI Weld + tomcat7 injection not working

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, cdi

I have tomcat7 server on ubuntu12.10
when I run my webapp via tomcat service start CDI works fine, but when I run it via Intellij IDEA tomcat runner(<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), I get error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [InjectedClass] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.sotas.test.Serv.injectedClass]
```

what's wrong?

```
Servlet:

@WebServlet(name = "serv", urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class Serv extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    InjectedClass injectedClass;
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }
    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(1);
        response.getWriter().println(injectedClass.getSomething());
    }
}
```

Injected class:

```
@RequestScoped
public class InjectedClassImplOne implements InjectedClass {
    @Override
    public String getSomething() {
        return "InjectedClassImplOne";
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
              factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
    <Listener className="org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldLifecycleListener"/>
</Context>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sotas.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>eetest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>eetest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
          <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>weld-tomcat-support</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>

  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I found the error....
I change the folder where beans.xml is detected.
Before was in
  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
And now
  src/main/resources/META-INF and works !!!

Comment: Just as another point.  You're pointing to CDI API 1.2, but using a CDI 1.0 implementation.  If you want it to work for CDI 1.2, using Weld Servlet 2.2.3.Final.

Comment: I'm interested in learning how you went about starting this project. Do you have a tutorial or any reference material I could use?